# discord.js - Stupid errors in one command

Tags: javascript, node.js, syntax, discord, discord.js

recently I installed discord.js-music via NodeJS. Upon making the command and executing the bot, I get this error:

```
});
 ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
```

So, logically, I removed the ")" even though I knew it was required, and I get THIS error:

```
});
 ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
```

My code is:

```
const Client = require('discord.js').Client;
const music = require('discord.js-music');

class Music extends patron.Command {
    constructor() {
        super({
            names: ['play'],
            groupName: 'general',
            description: 'joins your voice channel and plays the requested music.',
            args: [
                new patron.Argument({
                    name: 'message',
                    key: 'message',
                    type: 'message',
                    example: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DArzZ3RvejU',
                    defaultValue: patron.ArgumentDefault.message,
                    remainder: true
                })
            ]
        });
    };

    async run(msg, args) {
        if (String.isNullOrWhiteSpace(args.command)) {
            await msg.reply('you didn\'t specify the URL or search for music to play.')
            music(client);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Two things I see - you have a quoted closing bracket (second-to-last line of your code), and too few closing brackets.  So you'll need to unquote the one, and add another at the end.

Comment: @theGleep How did you managed to read this? ;)

Comment: Do you know the lines that the error points to? Note that you can format blocks of code with the {} button when editing your question, kinda weirdly formatted right now. I assume the two <br> tags are not part of the error message?

Comment: Copied the code to the clipboard, In the "your answer" box, I clicked the "code" button - after the "picture" button.  Pasted into the "javascript" section and clicked "tidy".

Comment: @Confuzing Yes, the BR tags were mistakes :/

Comment: Just thought I would mention that just because the error tells you `Unexpected token` doesn't mean that item isn't supposed to be there. It often means that the compiler was expecting to find something else before that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your code there is a missing closing curly braces } in second part that is in the async run function part.

Comment: Missing characters from code are a reason to close the question as "simple typographical error"